# Kendo grid set min and max value to another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this grid demo and what I want to achieve when radio percentage is checked amount value cannot be more than 100. I already create the function in `edit` event to set max and min value. But it still not working because it didn't fetch an `amount` id. Any help how to fetch the id?

[DEMO HERE](https://dojo.telerik.com/aLumucOL)

```js
var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  editable: true,
  //toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add" }],
  columns: [

    { field: "name", title: "name" },

    { field: "status", title: "Status",
      template: data => data.status == "amt" ? "Amount" : "Percentage",
         editor:    "<input name='status' type='radio' data-bind='checked:status' id='perc' value='perc'>" +
                "<label>Percentage</label><br>" +
                "<input name='status' type='radio' data-bind='checked:status' id='amt' value='amt'>" +
                "<label>Amount</label>"
        },
    { field: "amount", title: "Amount",
        //template: "<div class='amount'>#: amount #</div>",
        //template: "<a href='\\\#' id = '" + amount + "' class='deleteBtn'></a>",
    },
    { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }
  ],
  edit: function(e){


      $("#perc").click(() => {
            //alert('perc');
        if ($("#amount").val() > 100) $("#amount").val(100);
        $("#amount").attr({"max": 100, "min": 0 });
      });

      $("#amt").click(() => {
        //alert('amt');
        $("#amount").removeAttr("max");
        $("#amount").removeAttr("min");
      });


      $("input[name=amount]").change(() => {
          if ($("#perc").prop('checked')) {
          if ($("#amount").val() > 100) $("#amount").val(100);
        }
      });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrap the edit event handler.

Instead, use the [`columns.editor`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editor) function. It gets the entire row in `options.model`, so if `options.model.status` is percent, add the min and max attributes to the input.

Comment: Can you pls help me, I still not able to call the `('input[name="amount"]')`. [DOJO DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/aLumucOL/3)

Comment: `if(options.model.status == 'perc'){ input.kendoNumericTextBox({max: 100}); }`